# QtSettings not accessing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c++, qt

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here. It appears that my Qt Application will not retrieve the value from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

```
QSettings sys_app_settings(QSettings::NativeFormat, QSettings::SystemScope, "JokerMartini", "Hyv");
qDebug() << "SYS" << sys_app_settings.value("config", "").toString();
```

You can even see in the image below that i have the information available but it will not retrieve it for whatever reason. It just returns the default value of "" Any suggestions?

[image]

**Build Information:**
Windows 64bit
Desktop Qt 5.10.1 MinGW 32Bit

Running application on windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit application on 64 bit Windows by any chance?

Comment: Try `qDebug()<<QSettings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\JokerMartini\\Hyv",
                    QSettings::Registry64Format).value("config");`

Comment: Mention the compiler & os shall be helpful for answering.

Comment: your suggestion fixed it thank you.